# How to insert value of an array inside onSnapshot function from firebase which is also inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, for-loop

If I put the arr.push() outside the onSnapshot function that's the only time the array will return the value. But all I want is to insert the data within onSnapshot. Is anyone here can help me on this kind of problem?

```
inboxTodo.get().then(snap => {
      let arr = [] //Initialize array.
      snap.data().todos.forEach(todo => {
        cars.doc(String(doc.data().id)).collection('todo').doc(String(todo))
        .onSnapshot(t => {
          const value = {
            id: doc.data().id,
            value: t.data()
          }
          arr.push(value) // insert some data inside the array.
          this.props.setTodo(value)
        }, err => {
          alert(err)
        })
      }, err => {
        alert(err)
      })
      console.log(arr) //returns an empty array :(
    }, err => {
      alert(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.onSnapshot` takes a callback, which is asynchronous. So when your `console.log` executes, none of the `.onSnapshot` callbacks have been resolved, hence why your array is still empty.
You can know when all of the snapshot callbacks have fired by Promisifying them. 
You'll need to do something like this: (untested)

```js
inboxTodo.get().then(snap => {
      let promiseArr = [] // make an array of promises to be executed
      
      snap.data().todos.forEach(todo => {
      
      // Promisify each .onSnapshot
      promiseArr.push(new Promise(resolve => {
          cars.doc(String(doc.data().id)).collection('todo').doc(String(todo))
        .onSnapshot(t => {
          const value = {
            id: doc.data().id,
            value: t.data()
          }
          resolve(value) // resolve the new promise

          this.props.setTodo(value)
        }, err => {
          alert(err)
        })
        });
      }, err => {
        alert(err)
      })
      
      // exectue all promises
      Promise.all(promiseArr)
        .then(values => {
          console.log(values) // all your array values will be here
        })
    }, err => {
      alert(err);
    })
```